# How to handle these class-function calls the Pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm relatively new to Python and I am just getting into classes. I have something bit complicated in my hands that I want to solve the right and Pythonic way.

I want to have a class, say, '**books**'.
I want this class to handle two python dictionaries with different structures, say, '**chemistry**' and '**(english) dictionary**'.
I want to be able to perform actions on these two python dictionaries with different structures, such as '**find**', '**add**', '**remove**', '**list**' etc.

Since these two structures, '**chemistry**' and '**dictionary**' are different, '**add**', '**remove**' and '***find***' functions will need to have different code structures. So when I am finding something in '**chemistry**', the code block to be executed is different than **'finding' in 'dictionary'**.

My questions:

- How should I structure this class?
- How should I make calls on it?
- Ultimately, I would be happiest if function calls looked like: `books.chemistry.find('keyword to find')` and `books.dictionary.find('other keyword to find')`. Is this possible? How can I get it like this?

Thank you.

Comment: You both have a specific way you want the calls to look, and you want them to be Pythonic -- those may be mutually exclusive.

Comment: agf, that's exactly my question. That's why I am asking if it's possible or not. I am seeking to understand 3 things. The structure, the way calls being made on that structure and finally if calls as I structured are python and if possible. now if you have an answer to any of these questions, especially the first two, I would be most delighted, thank you.

Comment: `books.dictionary.find`? this doesn't make any sense are you searching through all the books?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you also want to share some methods between your classes so you can have a `Book` class with general properties and then a `Chemistry` and `English` class defining different `find` methods and inheriting properties or methods from `Book`:

```
class Books(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.input = dictionary
    def commonMethod(self):
        print 'This is a shared method'

class Chemistry(Books):
    def find(self):
        print 'This is a particular method'

class English(Books):
    def find(self):
        print 'This is other particular method'

chemistryBook = Chemistry({'hello': 'goodbye'})
chemistryBook.find()
# This is a particular method

EnglishBook = English({'hello': 'goodbye'})
EnglishBook.find()
# This is other particular method
```

**UPDATE**

I didn't read the last part of your message. Maybe this is what you want:

```
class Books(object):
    def __init__(self, dictionary):
        self.input = dictionary
        if len(dictionary) > 1:
            print 'More than 1'
            self.command = Chemistry(self.input)
        else:
            print 'Less or equal'
            self.command = English(self.input)

class Chemistry(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
    def find(self):
        print "Now you can manipulate your dictionary in Chemistry", self.d

class English(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
    def find(self):
        print "Now you can manipulate your dictionary in English", self.d


book = Books({'hello': 'goodbye'})
book.command.find()
# Less or equal
# Now you can manipulate your dictionary in English {'hello': 'goodbye'}

book2 = Books({'hello': 'goodbye', 'one': 1})
book2.command.find()
# More than 1
# Now you can manipulate your dictionary in Chemistry {'hello': 'goodbye', 'one': 1}
```

Basically this creates a particular instance of a class that is needed depending on the input. In this case, if the dictionary you pass as argument has length > 1 it creates an instance of Chemistry(). Otherwise, it creates an instance of English(). After that, you can use the find method.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Here's what I would do.

class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

class Book(object):

    def __init__(self, pages):

        if type(pages) == Page:
            self.pages = [pages]
        elif type(pages) == list:
            self.pages = pages

    def find(self, term):

        for page in self.pages:
            if term in page.text:
                return True
        return False

class ChemistryBook(Book):

    def __init__(self, pages):

        super(ChemistryBook, self).__init__(pages)

    #def someChemistryBookSpecificMethod(self):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    page = Page("Antoine Lavoisierb")
    chemBook = ChemistryBook(page)
    print chemBook.find("Antoine")
```